# Connect to the mysql database with spring web application in openshift

Tags: java, mysql, spring, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a spring web application with `openshift`. My database configurations are in `spring-database.xml` file.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
```

Openshift says to modify the url as `mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/`

But this didn't work. Then I tried with the host number and port number which showed in `phpmyadmin`. But still it says `Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The error is not very descriptive, I'd check db name, user name & password too. You can access those using environment variables too, but I'm not sure about proper referring them from spring-database.xml. When you say 'Openshift says to modify url as', you can perhaps link a blog or article where it is put that way?